# how to get next element by java script

Tags: javascript

I would like to get next element:

```
<script>
function editMediaInfo(mediaID){
   var x = document.getElementById(mediaID);
   alert(x.nextElementSibling.id);
}
</script>

<?php
    $x = 1;
    echo "<ol>";

    while($x <= 5)
     {
        echo "<li id={$x}> item {$x} </li>";
        $x++;
    ?>
        <button onclick="editMediaInfo('<?php echo $x; ?>')">Click</button>
    <?php
    }

    echo "</ol>";
 ?>
```

When i click it gives me an alert without nothing. I would like to get the id of the next element.

Comment: *"how to get next element by java script"* Then why tag your question `php` and not `javascript`? I've fixed the tags for you.

Comment: And why not show your generated html? The php code isn't interesting

Comment: So what does `x` hold? Try print debugging.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are using an incorrect Javascript function. Use `nextSibling` function. Replace `nextElementSibling` with `nextSibling`. I provided a sample below.

```
<script>
 function editMediaInfo(mediaID){
   var x = document.getElementById(mediaID);
    alert(x.nextSibling.id);
}
</script>
```

Where I found and tried the solution was [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp). I would recommend using this site for help on Javascript in the future.

Comment: What is the mediaID value the editMediaInfo function receiving? When developing JavaScript I would recommend using console.log to assist with debugging. Try console.log(mediaID) in the first line of the function. You can see the log by checking the console of your broswer. In chrome it's menu->More Tools->developer tools->console

Answer (score -1):

Simply Use :

```
document.getElementById(mediaID).nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id
```

Comment: ok it's work but can you explain why you use (nextElementSibling) twice i can't understand it?

Comment: nextElementSibling gets the button element after <li> and you want the id of next <li>. Now mark it as correct answer.

Comment: so i have another question, how i can get the first an the last element?